# Как положить свой ProjectTemplate в раздел VisualSudio (Visual C#/Web)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Привет! Я пытаюсь затолкать свой шаблон проекта в (Visual C#/Web)(Аналогично тому как там лежит DevExpress Template Gallery на моём скриншоте). Пытаюсь сделать это следующими строками кода в файле MyTemplate.vstemplate:

```
<TemplateData>
<Name>My Template Gallery</Name>
<Description>Start Template Gallery</Description>
<Icon>myProj.ico</Icon>
<ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
<ProjectSubType>Web</ProjectSubType>
<TemplateGroupID>Web</TemplateGroupID>
<RequiredFrameworkVersion>4.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
<SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
<NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>0</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
<TemplateID>4d72892d-abc3-428d-8fa7-8421a83d6e0a</TemplateID>
<CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
<DefaultName>XafariApplication</DefaultName>
<ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Ручной способ

1. Создаете проект. Заполняете нужными начальными файлами для шаблона. Сохраняете.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   2. В меню Файл выбираете Экспорт шаблона.
      [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   3. В Wizard'е выбираете: Project Template.
      [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   4. Заполняете поля.
      [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   5. Архив закинется в папку `<Рабочая папка студии>\My Exported Templates` и в папку `<Рабочая папка студии>\Templates\ProjectTemplates` (если не сняли галку в wizard'е):
      [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   6. Этот архив нужно поместить в папку `<Рабочая папка студии>\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\Web` (ее нет, поэтому необходимо создать):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   7. Заходите в студию. И Profit.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### С помощью VSIX

1. Дожен быть готов архив. Смотри 1-5 пункты **ручного способа**.
2. Создаете проект VSIX.
3. В проекте создаете нужную иерархию папок. В данном случае получается следующая иерархия:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Закидывайте архив в папку `ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web`.
5. В манифесте указываете нужные данные. Затем заходите в пункт Assets и добавляете:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Сохраняетесь. Билдитесь. Запускаете VSIX. Открываете студию.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### ProjectTemplate + VSIX

1. Создаете проект типа ProjectTemplate заполняете его.
2. Выбираете в студии файл с расширением *.vstemplate (по умолчанию его имя совпадает с именем проекта). И в его свойствах в строке ***Category*** прописываете путь иерархии, который будет начинаться от CSharp. Т.е. если указываете `SubA/SubB/SubC`, то шаблон будет лежать в `CSharp/SubA/SubB/SubC`. В нашем случае указываем только `Web`:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Создаем проект VSIX.
4. В манифесте указываете нужные данные:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Билдитесь.

**P.S.** Немного про элемент **TemplateData**.
Вы указали `ProjectSubType` значение `Web`, но этот элемент может иметь только всего 4 значения:

1. **SmartDevice-NETCFv1** - указывает поддержку .NET Compact Framework версии 1.0
2. **SmartDevice-NETCFv1** - указывает поддержку .NET Compact Framework версии 2.0
3. **CSharp** - Задается только тогда, когда элемент `ProjectType` имеет значение `Web` (т.е. это проект типа веб-сайт). Указывает на языка программирования.
4. **VisualBasic** - тоже самое, что и предыдущий пункт, только язык программирования `VisualBasic`.

Comment: @V.Dmitriy, привет. У zip файла: build action - это контент. Необязательно копировать во выходную директорию, т.к. при билде он все равно упакуется во vsix. А с Project Template как будет время, обновлю ответ.

Comment: Здравствуйте @nuts119! Огромное спасибо за помощь! У меня не выходит сделать "VSIX метод" какие свойства должны быть установлены архиву и проекту содержащему его?

Comment: @V.Dmitriy, ответил выше. Лагануло с комментом? Еще сейчас обновлю про ProjectTemplate.

Comment: @V.Dmitriy, обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, что-то лагануло. Все работает, спасибо @nuts119!

Comment: @V.Dmitriy, пожалуйста)